# Wrong query when trying to implement subquery

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, subquery

I have this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT
         TT.RECID, TT.TRANSDATE,
         TT.DATAAREAID, TT.SOURCERECID,
         TT.SOURCECURRENCYCODE, TT.TAXAMOUNT,
         TT.TAXBASEAMOUNT, TT.TAXBASEAMOUNTCUR,
         TT.TAXAMOUNTCUR, TT.TAXORIGIN,
         TT.VOUCHER, TT.TAXITEMGROUP,
         TT.TAXCODE, TT.SOURCEBASEAMOUNTCUR,
         TT.SOURCETAXAMOUNTCUR,
         TTGJAERIVA.TAXTRANSRELATIONSHIP,
         TTGJAERIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY,
         TTGJAERIVA.LEDGERDIMENSION,
         GJAERIVA.TEXT,
         GJAERIVA.LEDGERDIMENSION AS LEDGERDIMENSIONGAE,
         GJAERIVA.POSTINGTYPE
     FROM 
         TAXTRANS TT 
     INNER MERGE JOIN 
         TAXTRANSGENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY TTGJAERIVA ON TTGJAERIVA.TAXTRANS = TT.RECID
     INNER MERGE JOIN 
         GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY GJAERIVA ON TTGJAERIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY = GJAERIVA.RECID 
                                             AND GJAERIVA.POSTINGTYPE IN (14, 236, 71, 41) 
     WHERE  
         (TT.TAXORIGIN <> 11 
          AND TT.TRANSDATE BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-04-30') 
         OR 
         (TT.TAXORIGIN = 11 
          AND TT.TRANSDATE BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-04-30' )) AS T

---- --JOIN 
LEFT MERGE JOIN 
    (SELECT  
         SOURCERECID, TAXITEMGROUP, TAXCODE, 
         GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY, VOUCHER, TAXAMOUNT,
         TAXAMOUNTCUR 
     FROM 
         T) TTRIVA ON T.VOUCHER = TTRIVA.VOUCHER 
                   AND T.SOURCERECID = TTRIVA.SOURCERECID 
                   AND TT.TAXITEMGROUP = TTRIVA.TAXITEMGROUP 
                   AND (TTRIVA.TAXCODE LIKE 'RIVA%')
                   AND TTRIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY = TTGJAE.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY
```

I get an error:

> Invalid object name 'T'.

into subquery, just after left merge join (at the final of query)

```
---- --JOIN 
LEFT MERGE JOIN 
   (SELECT 
        SOURCERECID, TAXITEMGROUP, TAXCODE,
        GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY, VOUCHER,
        TAXAMOUNT, TAXAMOUNTCUR 
    FROM 
        T) TTRIVA ON T.VOUCHER = TTRIVA.VOUCHER 
                  AND T.SOURCERECID = TTRIVA.SOURCERECID 
                  AND TT.TAXITEMGROUP = TTRIVA.TAXITEMGROUP 
                  AND (TTRIVA.TAXCODE LIKE 'RIVA%')
                  AND TTRIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY = TTGJAE.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY
```

I don´t know why it occurs  if I use 'T' as result of query before join? Regards

Comment: You might want to break up the SQL. This is going to be a maintenance nightmare in future.

Comment: Believe me, its a nightmare now @DhimanBhattacharya

Comment: Side note: Especially on SQL Server, please [don't use `BETWEEN`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  I'm not completely convinced that `transdate` is a date, as opposed to a full timestamp

Answer (score 0):

As always, careful formatting is useful to reveal errors in SQL
syntax.

```
SELECT * FROM (
       SELECT
    TT.RECID,
    -- etc
    GJAERIVA.POSTINGTYPE
    FROM TAXTRANS TT 
    INNER MERGE JOIN TAXTRANSGENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY TTGJAERIVA
          ON TTGJAERIVA.TAXTRANS = TT.RECID
    INNER MERGE JOIN GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY GJAERIVA
          ON TTGJAERIVA.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY = GJAERIVA.RECID 
          AND GJAERIVA.POSTINGTYPE IN( 14,236,71,41
) -- as ????
WHERE   
    (TT.TAXORIGIN <> 11 AND 
     TT.TRANSDATE BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-04-30')
OR  (TT.TAXORIGIN = 11 AND 
     TT.TRANSDATE BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-04-30')

) AS T
---- --JOIN 
     LEFT MERGE JOIN  --- etc.
```

The closing `)` before the first `WHERE` clause is probably not what
you want.

SQL is a declarative language.  It's much easier to use if you make
the declarations as clear as possible to the reader.  By reformatting your query, for instance, we can readily see the `WHERE` clause can be reduced to

```
WHERE TT.TRANSDATE BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-04-30'
```

because every `TT.TAXORIGIN` will equal 11, or not.